# MongoDB search by a model property that's a List/Array

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, .net-core

I declare my `FilterDefinition` as such:

```
var filter = Builders<Applicant>.Filter
    .Where(o=>o.languages.Contains(language));
```

Where `language` is a string. And the model's `languages` is declared as such:

```
[BsonElement("languages")]
public List<string> languages { get; set; }
```

The problem is, with `List.Contains()`, `filter` only filters the the strings that are exactly the same, including the case. For example, it filters out and excludes `"northern catalan"` because the returned collection does not contain that specific string value, it only contains `"Northern Catalan"`:

```
[
   {
       id: {XXXXXXX},
       name : 'France',
       languages: [
           'French',
           'Alsatian',
           'Basque',
           'Northern Catalan',
           'Breton'
       ]
   },
   {
       /* More documents */
   }
]
```

So how do I define the FilterDefinition with case insensitive filter?

Comment: MongoDB does not care if the value is in array or singular. And what you are asking for is a "regex match" as opposed to an "exact match".